# Where did the cut option go in Yosemite?

Tags: osx-yosemite

I tried to cut a file and place it somewhere else, but there simply isn't the option there to do this in Yosemite. <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> doesn't work and the option does not exist when I right click:

[image]

If you're wondering, I have full admin access.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't exist in Mavericks/ML/Lion either.

Cmd/C to Copy
Cmd/Opt/V to paste, simultaneously cutting from the previous location.

You can Move by Cmd/drag from one volume to another; same volume will always move by default.